# How do I convert a JSONObject to class object?

Tags: android, gson

I need to convert a JSONObject to a Location object using gson libraries for an android project of mine. I'm not sure on how to do this. Can anyone help me with this. Thanks in advance.

I have a code something like

```
JSONArray input = new JSONArray(extras.getString("loc_json"));
```

I wanted to convert the JSONObject taken from the JSONArray to a Location class object. I just wanted to know whether there is a function that does it directly.

Pardon me if I framed the question in a wrong way. Since I haven't got the direct function, I did it in this way.

```
 loc_temp = (Location) gson.fromJson(input.getJSONObject(i).toString(), Location.class);;
```

Sorry for the stupid question.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

[Here's a tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html) for GSON - I think it should help bolster your understanding.  Essentially the parsing is done like this:

```
String mJsonString = "...";
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser(); 
JsonElement mJson =  parser.parse(mJsonString);
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyDataObject object = gson.fromJson(mJson, MyDataObject.class);
```

Comment: It should be "new JsonParser().parse(...)".. spent few minutes trying to figure out what the problem was

Answer (score 13):

if you still want to use **org.json.JSONObject**:

```
org.json.JSONObject o;
ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
MyClass myClass = m.readValue(o.toString(), MyClass.class);
```

Comment: what is ObjectMapper here..?

Comment: I guess:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

Comment: How is it connected to gson?

Answer (score 3):

use **com.google.gson.JsonObject  & JsonArray**  instead of org.json.*

like this :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type typeOfT = new TypeToken<List<Location.class>>(){}.getType();
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject jo = (JsonObject) parser.parse(jsonStr);
JsonArray ja = jo.getAsJsonArray("memberName");
list = gson.fromJson(ja, typeOfT);
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert JSONObject to Model class::

```
val jsonObject = JSONObject(data[0].toString())
val jsonModel = jsonObject.getJSONObject(KEY.message).toString()
val chatModel = Gson().fromJson(model, ChatModel::class.java))
```

Answer (score 1):

For kotlin

```
 val objType = object : TypeToken<MyClass>() {

    }.getType()
    var myclassObj = gson.fromJson(value,objType)
```

or

```
 val objectResponse = Gson().fromJson(Gson().toJson(resp), MyClass::class.java)
```