# Android/Java: How to get the ArrayList<JSONObject> from an Activity to another?

Tags: java, android, bundle

I want to get a value passed from another activity, it works well with multiple type like JSONArray, String, etc... but i could not find the way to retrieve a ArrayList value.

I tried several way like this one with no success:

```
      ArrayList<JSONObject> poiArr;   
        JSONArray jsonPoints;  
        try {
            poiArr = new ArrayList<JSONObject>(bundle.getSparseParcelableArray("poiArr"));  
//here is the problem 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            jsonPoints = new JSONArray(bundle.getString("lesPoints"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I have this error message:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'java.lang.Object[] java.util.Collection.toArray()' on a null object
>   reference

Any ideas?

Comment: One method I can suggest is to convert your JsonObject to String and pass it using putStringArrayListExtra()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSONObject is not Parcelable, or even Serializable. So the only option you're left with is to utilize JSONObject's `toString()` method and then rely on using `putStringArrayListExtra()` of Intent to pass it to the other.

On the other activity, use `getExtras()` of Intent to receive and convert that to JSONObject by passing the String into its constructor & loop to form the ArrayList if required.

Say, the ArrayList of JSONObject is `sendingArr` :

```
List<String> sendingListOfStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < sendingArr.length(); i++) {
    sendingListOfStrings.add( sendingArr.getJSONObject(i).toString() );
}
```

Sending from ActivityOne to ActivityTwo:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityOne.this, ActivityTwo.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("sending_list", sendingListOfStrings);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then capture it = in the other:

```
ArrayList<JSONObject> receivingArr;
Bundle receivingListOfStrings = getIntent().getExtras();
ArrayList<String> list = receivingListOfStrings.getStringArrayList("sending_list");
for (int i = 0; i < receivingListOfStrings.length(); i++) {
    receivingArr.add( new JSONObject( receivingListOfStrings.get(i) ) );
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have two error messages => *get java.lang.string in BaseBundle cannot be applied to (int) for the receivingListOfStrings.get(i)* & => *Cannot resolve method length() for the receivingListOfStrings.length()*

Comment: I think I can use all of your code except the last loop for that seems not to work. But the rest works well. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome @ΩlostA! Thanks for accepting the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing **ArrayList< JSONObject >**, you can create a Parcelable/Serializable Java Object(Model) and convert JSONObject to Java Object and then pass **ArrayList< Model>**. 
Ultimately you have to convert this JSONObjcet somewhere in your project to use it.

To convert JSONObject to Model, please check this:

[How do I convert a JSONObject to class object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15282181/how-do-i-convert-a-jsonobject-to-class-object)