# How to send volley response to firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am sending information to a website using volley and receiving a `json` response, I try to send this response to my `firebase` database but it crashes with the error : `com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: No properties to serialize found on class org.json.JSONObject`

This is my code

```
 private FirebaseDatabase sushFirebaseDatabase;
 private DatabaseReference tbbbbbb;
 ..... 
   Request.Method.POST,burl, jsonobject,
   new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
       @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
           FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
           String userID = user.getUid();
           mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

           sushFirebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

           tbbbbbbb=sushFirebaseDatabase.getReference(Respons_Path);
           tbbbbbbb.child(userID).push().setValue(response);
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who would encounter the same problem, the simplest way is to save it to the database as a string, like this

```
   ........... 
   tbbbbbbb.child(userID).push().setValue(String.valueOf(response));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a **POJO** (Plain old Java Object) class and serialized your `JSONObject` to that POJO. Then Firebase can handle this.

To create POJO class you have to **ensure**:

1. **Either** all your required variables are **Public**
2. **Or** implement **getter/setter** for each required variables
3. **Or** implement proper public ***constructor*** to create object.

You can find [Plethora of Options here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15282181/how-do-i-convert-a-jsonobject-to-class-object#) to convert `JSONObject` to Class object.

Comment: So the data has to be converted to a class object in order to go to the database?